# How to solve this problem with Typscript installation?

Tags: typescript, terminal, npm-install

I tried to install Typescript, but I got a few error messages in my terminal after installing:

[image: screenshot]

And when I open the terminal in VS Code I get this error messages to:

```
bash: eval: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: eval: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
MacBook-Air-de-Aldo:Typescript aldodg$
```

Comment: Your issue is not about TypeScript. You have to learn how to use npm and to create a `package.json` first.

Comment: It says you're missing a `package.json` file. Try running `npm init` first?